# Are there lectures or notes on Vladimir Igorevich Arnold's Ordinary Differential Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Need some help to read this book. Thanks

Comment: I googled first, found nothing.

Comment: Good for you, then! (Those are the kind of "context" details that help us to help you best!)

Answer (score 2):

I doubt if there are any lectures following Arnold's book. But definitely there are many video lectures available on ODEs, the most famous being MIT's [open courseware](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/). Of course, Arnold goes well beyond the contents of those lectures and tends to use lot of geometric ideas. Nevertheless, OCW is a great resource.